# Opening webpage in new tab and timeouts

Tags: javascript

I am wondering, what is happening to the setTimeout's, setInterval's and other functions that trigger when the DOM is loaded, when I open the webpage in other tab or window. Do they trigger once I actually see the webpage, or they trigger once the DOM is loaded, even in the background? Is this different on different browsers?

Comment: they are triggered only once.. the page is loaded.. On reconstruction of dom .. they will not get triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in Chrome and Opera the callback *is* executed, even if the page is loaded in the background.

Consider the following HTML

```
<a href="javascript:openWindow()">Click me!</a>
```

and the respective JavaScript

```
function openWindow()
{
    var article = open('');
    focus();

    article.setTimeout(function(){ article.alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}
```

(See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mu875pff/5/)).

If you click on the link with the Ctrl-Key pressed, Chrome opens a new background tab. Still the `alert` is shown after 3 seconds. The same beaviour can be observed in Opera. I've tried Edge, too, but it won't open the page in a background tab, hence I cannot tell, if the JS would still be executed.

Comment: Alright. Do you know what happens if, for example, I open tab on iPhone Chrome, and go out of the app. Are the functions still running in the background?

Comment: Just give it a shot with the fiddle. I've just tried it with Chrome@Android and the alert did not show at all when I opened the tab in the background.

Comment: @uksz and don't forget to mark my answer as the correct one ;)